# QNetworkAccessManager send PUT request with JSON

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, qt5, qnetworkaccessmanager

I want to send a put request with JSON body, but with QNetworkAccessManager doesn't have the option to send a request with JSON so I converted it to QByteArray, the structure of the body, when converted to QByteArray, is not a JSON format so that I received an Error with

`"Error downloading https://example.api.com/something/DataSet('123456780XYZ') - server replied: Forbidden"`

The JSON format I want is like this:

```
{
    "d": {
        "Duration": "0.000",
        "Id": "123456780XYZ",
        "LoadCumulLimit": "0.000",
        "Notes": "send from postman in Json format"
    }
}
```

Here is what did I do

```
    QJsonObject data;
    data["Duration"] = workplace->data["duration"];
    data["Id"] = id;
    data["LoadCumulLimit"] = workplace->data["load_cumul_limit"];
    data["Notes"] = workplace->dataText["Notes"];

    QJsonObject newData;
    newData["d"] = data;
    QJsonDocument doc(newData);

    qDebug() << url;
    QByteArray finalData = doc.toJson();
    qDebug() << finalData;

    reply = manager->put(request, finalData);
    connect(reply, &QNetworkReply::finished, [=](){
        if(reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError){
                QString contents = QString::fromUtf8(reply->readAll());
                qDebug() << contents;
            }
            else{
                QString err = reply->errorString();
                qDebug() << err;
            }
            reply->deleteLater();
    });
```

But I received the QByteArray like this:
`"{\n    \"d\": {\n        \"Duration\": 8,\n        \"IgelId\": \"123456780XYZ\",\n        \"LoadCumulLimit\": 25,\n        \"Notes\": \"send from IGEL\"\n    }\n}\n"`

Comment: That looks like correct JSON to me. The `\n` and `\"` portions are just escape characters and are an artifact of how you are printing the `QByteArray`.

Comment: @DeanJohnson Do you know how to convert from QJson to QByteArray with in right order, such like in QJsonDocument, the order of element is 1-2-3-4, but when converted it to QByteArray, it becomes 2-1-3-4 or 4-1-2-3

Comment: No, there is no support for that because JSON is explicitly unordered. Two bits of JSON are considered equivalent even if their keys are in different orders.